# How to make background of BrowserField transparent in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, browserfield

I am using `BrowserField` component of **RIM BB**. It is right now displaying a white background. I want make a transparent background, so it could match with the Manager's background color.

I had tried with below code. But it's not working.

```java
BrowserField contentField = new BrowserField();
bgTransparent = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0xffffff, 0);    
contentField.setBackground(bgTransparent);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: will you try this ? setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK))

Comment: setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK)) is not working.

Comment: Check documentation of the method `setBackground(int color)` here, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#setBackground%28int%29. It says that, `color - the color to set the background to (in the form: 0xRRGGBB)`, and the value of color doesn't have any alpha value.

Comment: I applied this but its not working... :(

Comment: This isn't exactly making the background *transparent*, but if you are just looking to match the underlying background, [you can see this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15168757/119114) for a workaround.